# CSS - Change 'Handle' on Bubbles

Tags: html, css

I'm modifying some CSS/HTML that I found [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/6mifhkdc) that displays a iOS style chat message with bubbles. I wanted to swap the alignment of the blue and green bubbles which I've managed to do but the only thing I'm not sure about is how to change the little "handle" that appears in the bottom left and right corners around as well.

Here's how it currently looks:

```css
/* Bit of normalisation */

body {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: #222;
 font: 0.8125em/1.5 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
 padding: 40px 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
}

/* .bubble */

.bubble {
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 left bottom,
 left top,
 color-stop(0.25, rgb(210,244,254)),
 color-stop(1, rgb(149,194,253))
);
 border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 /* vendor rules */
 border-radius: 20px;
 /* vendor rules */
 box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 /* vendor rules */
 box-sizing: border-box;
 clear: both;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 8px 30px;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 width: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bubble:before, .bubble:after {
 border-radius: 20px / 10px;
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

.bubble:before {
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 bottom: 0;
 left: -7px;
 z-index: -2;
}

.bubble:after {
 border: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: #d2f4fe;
 bottom: 1px;
 left: -5px;
}

.bubble--alt {
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 left bottom,
 left top,
 color-stop(0.25, rgb(172,228,75)),
 color-stop(1, rgb(122,205,71))
);
 float: left;
}

.bubble--alt:before {
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 border-radius: 20px / 10px;
 left: auto;
 right: -7px;
}

.bubble--alt:after {
 border-bottom-color: #ace44b;
 border-radius: 20px / 10px;
 left: auto;
 right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 
 <div class="bubble">
  Blue text bubble
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble bubble--alt">
  Green text bubble
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble">
  A bubble containing lots and lots and lots and lots of content on multiple lines
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble bubble--alt">
  Bubble with image
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/600" alt="" />
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble">
  Bubblewitharidiculouslylongwordwhichwrapseffortlesslyontotwolines
 </div>
 
</div>
```

I can't work out how to swap the little handles in the bottom corners of each bubble so they are on the opposite side. I'd like the blue one appear from the bottom right corner and the green one appearing from the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your code. Is this what you want?

```css
/* Bit of normalisation */

body {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: #222;
 font: 0.8125em/1.5 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
 padding: 40px 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 400px;
}

/* .bubble */

.bubble {
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210,244,254) 25%, rgb(149,194,253) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 left bottom,
 left top,
 color-stop(0.25, rgb(210,244,254)),
 color-stop(1, rgb(149,194,253))
);
 border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 /* vendor rules */
 border-radius: 20px;
 /* vendor rules */
 box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 /* vendor rules */
 box-sizing: border-box;
 clear: both;
 float: right;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 8px 30px;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 width: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bubble:before, .bubble:after {
 border-radius: 20px / 10px;
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}

.bubble:before {
 border: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 bottom: 0;
 right: -7px;
 z-index: -2;
}

.bubble:after {
 border: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: #d2f4fe;
 bottom: 1px;
 right: -5px;
}

.bubble--alt {
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172,228,75) 25%, rgb(122,205,71) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
 linear,
 left bottom,
 left top,
 color-stop(0.25, rgb(172,228,75)),
 color-stop(1, rgb(122,205,71))
);
 float: left;
}

.bubble--alt:before {
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 border-radius: 20px / 10px;
 right: auto;
 left: -7px;
}

.bubble--alt:after {
 border-bottom-color: #ace44b;
 border-radius: 20px / 10px;
 right: auto;
 left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 
 <div class="bubble">
  Blue text bubble
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble bubble--alt">
  Green text bubble
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble">
  A bubble containing lots and lots and lots and lots of content on multiple lines
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble bubble--alt">
  Bubble with image
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/600" alt="" />
 </div>
 
 <div class="bubble">
  Bubblewitharidiculouslylongwordwhichwrapseffortlesslyontotwolines
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go full code:

> Under `.bubble:before{..}` and `.bubble:after {..}` you have used `left` property that should be of `right` and vice-versa for 'bubble--alt:before{..}`and`bubble--alt:after{..}`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #222;
  font: 0.8125em/1.5 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 40px 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}


/* .bubble */

.bubble {
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(210, 244, 254) 25%, rgb(149, 194, 253) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, right bottom, right top, color-stop(0.25, rgb(210, 244, 254)), color-stop(1, rgb(149, 194, 253)));
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* vendor rules */
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* vendor rules */
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* vendor rules */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bubble:before,
.bubble:after {
  border-radius: 20px / 10px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.bubble:before {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  right: -7px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.bubble:after {
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #d2f4fe;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: -5px;
}

.bubble--alt {
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(172, 228, 75) 25%, rgb(122, 205, 71) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.25, rgb(172, 228, 75)), color-stop(1, rgb(122, 205, 71)));
  float: left;
}

.bubble--alt:before {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px / 10px;
  right: auto;
  left: -7px;
}

.bubble--alt:after {
  border-bottom-color: #ace44b;
  border-radius: 20px / 10px;
  right: auto;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


  <div class="bubble">
    Blue text bubble
  </div>

  <div class="bubble bubble--alt">
    Green text bubble
  </div>

  <div class="bubble">
    A bubble containing lots and lots and lots and lots of content on multiple lines
  </div>

  <div class="bubble bubble--alt">
    Bubble with image
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/800/600" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="bubble">
    Bubblewitharidiculouslylongwordwhichwrapseffortlesslyontotwolines
  </div>

</div>
```